# how to make combination alphabet looping in java

Tags: java, loops

How to make combination alphabet looping in Java like example output like this

```
A1 B1 C1 D1
A1 B1 C1 D2
A1 B1 C1 D3
A1 B1 C2 D1
A1 B1 C2 D2
A1 B1 C2 D3
A1 B2 C1 D1
A1 B2 C1 D2
A1 B2 C1 D3
A1 B2 C2 D1
A1 B2 C2 D2
A1 B2 C2 D3
A1 B3 C1 D1
A1 B3 C1 D2
A1 B3 C1 D3
A1 B3 C2 D1
A1 B3 C2 D2
A2 B3 C2 D3
A2 B1 C1 D1
A2 B1 C1 D2
A2 B1 C1 D3
A2 B1 C2 D1
A2 B1 C2 D2
A2 B1 C2 D3
A2 B2 C1 D1
A2 B2 C1 D2
A2 B2 C1 D3
A2 B2 C2 D1
A2 B2 C2 D2
A2 B2 C2 D3
A2 B3 C1 D1
A2 B3 C1 D2
A2 B3 C1 D3
A2 B3 C2 D1
A2 B3 C2 D2
A2 B3 C2 D3
```

For this combination like matrix (36 x 4).
Column 1 is 18 for A1, 18 for A2.
Column 2 is 6 for B1, 6 for B2, 6 for B3.
Column 3 is 3 for C1, 3 for C2.
Column 4 is 1 for D1, 1 for D2, 1 for D3.
Every column have 36 data.
Thank's.

Comment: Use a couple of `for` loops.

Comment: What's the pattern exactly? How do you go from "A1 B1 C1 D2" to "A1 B1 C2 D3"? From that to "A1 B2 C2 D1"? From that to "A1 B2 C1 D2"? There's no logic to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the pattern is:
Main array have 4 elements(`A B C D`),

> - we loop from A to D
> - D have 3 elements(from D1 to D3)
> - C have 2 elemments(from C1 to C2)
> - B have 3 elements(from B1 to B3)
> - A have 2 elements(from A1 to A2)

Pseudocode:

```
String[2] A = {"A1","A2"};
String[3] B = {"B1","B2","B3"};
String[2] C = {"C1","C2"};
String[3] D = {"D1","D2","D3"};
for(int i = 0; i < A.length;i++){
   for(int j = 0;j < B.length;j++){
     for(int t = 0; t < C.length;t++){
        for(int e = 0; e < D.length;e++){
            System.out.printfln(A[i] + " " + B[j] + " " + C[t] + " " + D[e]);
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

People may attack me for giving away a fish.  So be it.

```
public class Scratch1
{
    private static class Nibble {
        private String[] symbols;
        private int      numSymbols;
        private int      numRepeats;

        public Nibble(int numRepeats, String... symbols) {
            this.symbols = symbols;
            this.numSymbols = symbols.length;
            this.numRepeats = numRepeats;
        }

        public String toString(int i) {
            return symbols[(i / numRepeats) % numSymbols];
        }
    }

    private static class Column {
        private Nibble firstNibble;
        private Nibble secondNibble;

        public Column(Nibble firstNibble, Nibble secondNibble) {
            this.firstNibble = firstNibble;
            this.secondNibble = secondNibble;
        }

        public String toString(int i) {
            return firstNibble.toString(i) + secondNibble.toString(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Column columns[] = {
            new Column( new Nibble(18, "A"), new Nibble(18, "1", "2")),
            new Column( new Nibble(18, "B"), new Nibble( 6, "1", "2", "3")),
            new Column( new Nibble( 6, "C"), new Nibble( 3, "1", "2")),
            new Column( new Nibble( 3, "D"), new Nibble( 1, "1", "2", "3"))
        };

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 36 ; i++) {
            for (int colNum = 0 ; colNum < columns.length ; colNum++) {
                if (colNum > 0) System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(columns[colNum].toString(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Feeding the help vampires :(